# haskell generating random sequence and passing the generator

Tags: haskell, random

I would like to create random sequences while still passing the randomGenerator `mkStdGen`

I have come up with the following, which seems to work, but I am wondering if there is a better/proper way of doing this?

```
genRandomSeq :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => Int -> (a,a) -> g -> ([a], g)
genRandomSeq n rng g =
  foldr (\_ (acc,g') -> (\(a,g'') -> (a:acc, g'')) (randomR rng g')) ([],g) [0..n]


-- which is basically the same as
genRandomSeq 0 rng g collected = (collected, g)
genRandomSeq n rng g collected =
  let (a,g') = randomR rng g in
  genRandomSeq (n - 1) rng g' (a : collected)


(xs,g)  = genRandomSeq 5 ('a','z') (mkStdGen 10)
(ys,g') = genRandomSeq 5 ('a','z') g

zs = "my nice string: " ++ xs ++ ys :: String
```

in use

```
*Main> genRandomSeq 5 ('a','z') (mkStdGen 10)
("rrsvfx",1928412403 1780294415)
*Main> zs
"my nice string: rrsvfxyaygon"
```

Comment: Remark: If code already works and you're interested in a review, it might be a candidate for [codereview.SE].

Comment: Not really. If all this explicit passing is bothering you you could wrap it in `State`, then your signature would look like `genRandomSeq :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => Int -> (a,a) -> State g [a]`, you be the judge of if you like that better.

Comment: MonadRandom (and MonadCryptoRandom) are two packages that keep the generator in a state monad for you and provide easy routines in the form `get me random(s) of type X`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that passing seeds explicitly is clunky, annoying and leads to poor composability.  My favored approach is to use a custom monad for random number generation.  [The `MonadRandom` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom) is the granddaddy of them all, I understand, but there's also [`random-fu`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu) which is more featureful but a bit harder to get started with.

Using `MonadRandom` and similar tools your function can be written this way (not tested, but it should be about right):

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import Control.Monad.Random

genRandomSeq :: Random a => Int -> (a,a) -> Rand g [a]
getRandomSeq n range = replicateM n (getRandomR range)

-- Your function is this, but in practice I might not bother writing it
-- out as its own definition—basically, I'd work in the `Rand` monad as 
-- much as possible and only `runRand` where I really need to.
runIt :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => Int -> (a,a) -> g -> ([a], g)
runIt n range g = runRand (getRandomSeq n range) g
```

If you haven't studied the `State` monad this would be a good point for you to do so.  The `Rand` monad is just a specialized state monad with a few utility functions to make it easier to work with random generation.

**EXERCISE:** Write your own version of the `Rand` type, its `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` instances, and the `getRandomR` operation.